# Which transatlantic airline has the most leg space in coach?

Tags: air-travel, health, airlines

Which transatlantic airline has the most leg space in the non-business section these days?

I recently traveled from Los Angeles to London Heathrow on Virgin Atlantic (Airbus 340, if I recall correctly) and I was certainly not impressed, and I am not a particularly tall person.

Comment: updated your title to include the word 'leg' as that's what you were asking in you question.  (Airlines also differ on seat width, so just trying to make it clear).  Hope that's ok.

Comment: Quite a few airlines on that route offer a non-business cabin "Premium Economy", which costs more than regular economy, but has bigger seats. Is that an option for you, or are you only interested in normal economy seats?

Comment: That is always an option, but as you know carries a premium. I was curious if there was any significant difference between the airlines wrt. this aspect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is not that easy to answer as the leg space is very different depending on plane, airline and therefore route.

Anyhow I didn't found any leg space database/comparison on the web till now. But there is another indicator you can use which is mostly up to date - the seat pitch.

> **Seat Pitch:** The distance between two rows of seats, this is the best indicator of legroom. More is better.

On a quick look, it is mostly United, KLM, Delta, AA on their long-haul Eco Flights. But make sure that you check the aircraft model too.

You should take a look at http://www.seatguru.com/charts/longhaul_economy.php#chart

Comment: SeatGuru is a great resource for people interested in leg room.  I use it frequently, as a 6'4" air traveller.